# Strong parameters - manual whitelisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For a new rails app:

```
rails generate scaffold user name:string
```

This works fine in the controller:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
```

But this...

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).tap do |whitelist|
        whitelist[:name] = params[:user][:name]
    end
end
```

... gives me an error "ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError"

Why so?  Looking at examples of tap/whitelisting, it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to tweak it a little bit like this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name).tap do |whitelist|
    whitelist[:name] = params[:user][:name]
  end
end
```

permit the `attribute` before calling `.tap` method